# how to change UserId/Password in multiple queries simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several queries to an external db. For all of them, I let Excel save both UserId and Password (not a big security concern, at the moment).
Quite often I need to run the same set of queries against different db schema, that is, by logging in using different UserId/Password (s).
Is there a way (even with VBA) to set the same UserId/Password for all my queries simultaneously , without having to modify each query's properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that's possible without changing the connection properties. Record Macro might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I put together the following VBA code, that seems to do what I need.

```
Sub UpdateCredentials(ByVal userid As String, ByVal userpwd As String)

Dim ConnString As String
Dim newString As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    For o = 1 To ws.ListObjects.Count
        ConnString = ws.ListObjects(o).QueryTable.Connection
        i1 = InStr(1, ConnString, "UID", vbTextCompare)
        i2 = InStr(1, ConnString, "PWD", vbTextCompare)
        If i2 = 0 Then i2 = i1 + 2
        i3 = InStr(i2, ConnString, ";", vbTextCompare)

        newString = Left(ConnString, i1 + 3) + userid + ";PWD=" + userpwd + ";" + Right(ConnString, Len(ConnString) - i3)

        ws.ListObjects(o).QueryTable.Connection = newString

    Next o
Next
```

End Sub